# Double For Loop in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, double

```
 Dim ssi(11) As String

   For i = 0 To 10
    If ssi(i) = "" Then ssi(i) = "0"

    For j = 0 To Val(ssi(11)) + i
      ssi(i) = xuh(Val(ssi(i)))
    Next


  Next

  If ssi(11) = "2" Then
     L_zz.Caption = Val(Left(ssi(0) & ssi(1) & ssi(2) & ssi(3) & ssi(4) & ssi(5) & ssi(6) & ssi(7), ssi(10)))
  ElseIf ssi(11) = "3" Then
     L_zz.Caption = Val(Left(ssi(0) & ssi(1) & ssi(2) & ssi(3) & ssi(4) & ssi(5) & ssi(6) & ssi(7), ssi(10))) * (-1)

  End If
```

I am new here and new to VB as well.

I am trying to understand this double loop in vb code.
ssi(i) is defined as a String variable. and each element is assigned to a specific number in a String. Hope I told it clearly.

My problem with this loop is below.
Since i ranges from 0 to 10, what does this j mean? Does j mean the new ssi(1-10) or another whatever number?

Comment: `j` will be whatever the numeric value of the string in `ssi(11)` is, plus the current value of `i`.  So if the value of `ssi(11)` was 10, for example, then it would be the first inner loop would be 0 to 10, the next inner loop would be 0 to 11, ect.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?  What is in the 12 strings defined by ssi?

Comment: However, I think the current code as posted will throw an error, because `ssi(11)` is out of bounds for the array.   You declare it as a string array with 11 elements - but `ssi(11)` is the **12th** element.  Remember arrays are 0-based in .NET.

Comment: This code does not make too much sense (and the Val function part should be replaced). You are making the internal loop depend upon ssi(11) but you are never populating this value (the loop goes until 10). Also the fact of having an array with 12 elements and iterating only through the first 11 ones indicate that there is an error in the algorithm. Same thing for the conditions below: they refer to an index (11) which is always null and thus none of them will ever be met.

Comment: @Tim it is not out of the bounds of the array (and thus no error will be thrown: `Val` will take care of the null strings). This array has 12 positions (`Dim ssi(11) As String` means that the last index is 11; not that its length is 11 like in C#). In any case, this code will not work, as explained in my comment above.

Comment: @Tim no problem. It is a common error when dealing with both, C# and VB :)

Comment: why does that code look like it already went thru an obfuscator?

Comment: This has the makings of some awesomely bad code. 1) string math, 2) special values in the array (`ssi(10)`,`ssi(11)`,..) 3) Using `&` instead of `string.Join()` 4)  Setting a string (`.Caption`) from a double without any formatting 5) Copy and Paste programming 6) No descriptive methods to reuse common code, and the list goes on.. Oh please post it on http://thedailywtf.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to answer your question about understanding a double loop is to try looking at something simpler.

The first program I always write in each new version of BASIC that comes along is a 12 times table.

I've modified it a bit below to be a 12 x 10 table for the purpose of illustrating for you how a double loop works ... hope it helps:

```
 For x As Integer = 1 To 12
        For y As Integer = 1 To 10
            Console.Write(x * y)
            Console.Write(vbTab)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
 Next
```